# Function for filtering columns with dates

Tags: excel, vba

```
ID No.                          
WP1 252 Main Deck       √           5kg     Jan-20  
WP1 4025    Main Deck       √       5kg     Jan-20  
WP1 TBC Main Deck       √           5kg     Jan-20  
WP1 PENDING Main Deck       √       5kg     
WP1 # 147   Main Deck   √           25kg    Nov-18  
WP1 200 Boat Landing    √           9kg     Oct-18  
    ID No.
```

I am trying to count different dates in my table using VBA. But I can't reach to a solution.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Remember, we know nothing about your problem except what you share. Please share more information. What is the setup? What does the end result look like? Are the strings above all in one cell? More is better

Comment: So would the answer here be 3 for unique dates or 5 for total dates?

Comment: use `countif` or `countifs` formula. No need for VBA here.

Comment: If you insist doing this in  vba *(although it makes no sense to)*, then at least post your code

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a simple case of [`=COUNTIF()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countif.php)

[image]

Then again, this situation almost begs for a  [pivot-table](/questions/tagged/pivot-table)

[image]